# Syntax error on token "b", delete this token

Tags: java, token

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Demo1_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a,b,c,d;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("请输入金字塔层数:");
        a = sc.nextInt();
        for(b=1;b<=a;b++){
            for(c=1;c<=a-b;c++){
                System.out.println(" ");
            }
            for(d=1;d<=2b-1;d++){
                System.out.println("*");
                }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The exception shows:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      Syntax error on token "b", delete this token at none.Demo1_1.main(Demo1_1.java:15)

What's wrong with the B token?

Comment: There is error on this line `for(d=1;d<=2b-1;d++)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `d<=2b-1` (because Java won't assume that's multiplication)

```
for(d=1;d<=2b-1;d++){
```

I think you wanted `d<=(2*b)-1;` like

```
for(d=1;d<=(2*b)-1;d++){
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of 2b it should be 2*b

```
for(d=1; d <= 2*b -1; d++){
```

Answer (score 1):

**2b-1 is** a math expression that must be in java as **2*b -1**

```
for(d=1;d<=2b-1;d++){
```

this in not correct, you mean for sure

```
for(d=1;d<=2*b-1;d++){
```